# No such module Crashlytics - Pod seems to be missing

Tags: swift, xcode, crashlytics

I constantly get an error "No such module Crashlytics" and I usually resolve it with hours of cleaning build folder, reinstalling everything, running pod install, etc, but I'm getting tired of this and want to fix the problem once and for all.

My podfile contains this entry:

```
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
```

I suspect the issue may be that my project is in an icloud directory and sometimes it doesn't download everything locally in an attempt to save drive space, but either way here is what I am seeing and would like some help:

**My pods in navigation tree (notice Crashlytics)**

[image: My pods on navigation tree]

Now what's interesting is that when I go to add the framework directly (Link Binary with Libraries) that all the other modules are there in my Pods location except Crashlytics!

**So here you see it's not there in Pods!** [image]

Any ideas what's going on? I suspect this is an important reason why it is not seeing this.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to delete all the 4 pods files (Podfile, Podfile.lock, .xcworkspace and the foldern Pods) and then pod init and reinstall all your pods?

Comment: hey @mat yes I just tried that did the track. my god. It actually wasn't enough I had do all that, then delete derived data, then clean/build. thank you very much if you'd like to post this as an answer I can give you credit, I forgot about the trick of deleting pods

Comment: Glad it solved the problem. It happened to me in the past as well. I have just answered the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do the following:

Delete all 4 pods related files:

1. Podfile
2. Podfile.lock
3. yourprojectname.xcworkspace
4. Pods folder

Then reinstall everything again with `pod init` and `pod install`