# Pod Install remove/delete some unrelated object/property

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'd like to remove a Pod called EvernoteSDK from my project.
I remove the pod by execute these steps:

1. Remove 'EvernoteSDK' from Podfile
2. Run **pod install**

Result:

The EvernoteSDK has been removed. But when I check the diff, It deletes some object/property in some **xcconfig** file that I think it should be not related to the removed Pod. And this change is occurred in all installed Pod of my project. The diff result is shown in the image below:

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cywbN.png)

My environment:

1. xCode 12
2. I tried it by using Cocoapods 1.9.3

Why is it happened? And how to remove a pod without affect other Pod file?
Because this is my first time to face this issue when removing a Pod.

Thank you.

Comment: I would advice you to remove all your pods as explained in my answer to the following question. After that you can reinstall the Pod you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696726/no-such-module-crashlytics-pod-seems-to-be-missing/60701426#60701426

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to version of Cocoapods. That difference is probably some new config from Cocoapods, so everything should be alright.