# Xcode12.4 Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets

Tags: swift, xcode, sdk, admob, cocoapods

I have been trying to update Pods, however, I get this warning every time I run `pod update`.

[image]

Here are the Excluded Architectures of the Project and Pods respectively.

[image]

[image]

#### What I've tried

- Added this snippet to the top of Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

- Removed Podfile.lock and Pods directory and run `pod install`
- Almost followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-object-file-built-for-ios) except for adding this snippet since I do not have `.podspec` file.

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
```

It would be great if you have advice and tips.

Thanks.

### [Update] February 23, 2021 (PST)

I have not figured out this, can anyone help me to solve it, please?

#### Things I did additionally

- Added this snippet to the top Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "YES"
    end
  end
end
```

- Tried to remove `VALID_ARCHS` from the Target, however, it's not removable. Also, replace them with blank. Nothing changes.

#### Curious

This is a screenshot of the build settings of Pods.
[image]
`Build Active Architecture Only` for `Release` is currently set `No`. Even if I change this to `Yes`, it's overwritten. Is this fine with leaving it as `No`?

Comment: I would advice you to do what I suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696726/no-such-module-crashlytics-pod-seems-to-be-missing/60701426#60701426

Comment: @Mat Thank you for your suggestion. I removed all `.workspace`, `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock`, and `Pods` and run `pod init`, and `pod install`. But still getting the warning.

Comment: Did it work before? Have you made any changes or just updated it?

Comment: Had never tried before. That was the first time removing them since you suggested for me.

Comment: I mean, when did you start getting the above error?

Comment: I updated to Xcode12.4. But it might have been there evem before and I didn't notice the warning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228936/discussion-between-mat-and-bob).

Comment: I have been suffering the same issue for last 2 months. Any update? Please response!

Comment: @Tulon I've been busy and haven't completely solved this issue yet. I haven't even tried what Eric suggested below. In my case, I use real devices and don't use simulators at all when I check if everything works. These warnings are telling us that there may be problems when we use simulators. Even though we see the warnings, it doesn't mean you can't update Pods. I think you have already got the latest SDKs. But if you use simulators, there is nothing that I can say at the moment. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

In the short term, working around it in your podspec can work. Try this:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "i386 arm64"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

See [source](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8967#issuecomment-509047159) for more info.

Longer term, start asking those library maintainers to stop relying on `user_target_xcconfig`.

I maintain `GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook` and we learned this the hard way. The [version 6.3.0.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/4/1/b/GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook/6.3.0.0/GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook.podspec.json#L22-L25) spec has been updated to set `VALID_ARCHS` at the `pod_target_xcconfig` level only. We plan to make the same changse to `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` in an upcoming release. But those other ads SDKs will need to do the same.